# Proof nonpositivity of a particular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let **A** be a nonnegative matrix and let *h* be its largest eigenvalue. Is it true that the inverse of (**A** - *g* **I**) is a nonpositive matrix if *h* < *g*?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as $g>h=\rho(A)$, we have $\rho\left(\frac{A}{g}\right)<1$ and hence we may expand $\left(I-\frac{A}{g}\right)^{-1}$ as a Neumann series. Consequently,
$$
(A-gI)^{-1}=\left[-g\left(I-\frac{A}{g}\right)\right]^{-1}=-\frac{1}{g}\left(I+\frac{A}{g}+\frac{A^2}{g^2}+\cdots\right)\le0.
$$